# Processing eclipse android resource file papplet

Tags: android, eclipse, processing

When I create a pimage in a papplet for an android activity, I want to locate the image location. I read online that you need to store it in a /assets folder in the root directory of the project, but this isn't being recognized for some reason, are there any other steps needed like include the folder in build path or something??

Answer (score 0):

To locate a resource in android you put it in the "assets" directory and you load it with: "file:///android_asset/[name of the file.extension]"

Comment: so for a PImage i would use `loadImage("file:///android_asset/mypic.png")`